# JPATH ISSUE::Joomla in Sub-Directories

Tags: joomla

When  I have shifted my site on **/var/www/ to /var/www/mysite/**
 then i think JPATH_ROOT give me path (/var/www/mysite) but My JPATH_ROOT is give (var/www/).
**Why**....???? :(
Note:I'm using **multi_site component**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jpath_root is defined programmatically so the issue is going to be in the multi site component most likely. Try uninstalling the component and see if it works.

Comment: Thats fine, i have try this. but i want to use this component... :( Let me know any patching  for resolving this issue

Comment: You should be able to use the component, it is likely a configuration issue in the component. I only recommend uninstalling to insure that your install works properly. If you uninstall and it works, then you know the problem is in the component. I am not familiar with the config on this, but due to the nature of how it works I would imagine there are settings you can tinker with to make it work.